# Concatenar varios registros en una sola fila

Tags: php, jquery, sql, sql-server

Como puedo juntar los registros de la Linea y los productos en una sola celda para que no aparezcan varios registros como se muestran en la imagen, solo quiero que aparezca una sola vez el nombre y sus datos de la persona y en la columna de Linea y Producto que se guarden todas la Lineas o los Productos que tiene asignados esa persona.

La consulta que estoy realizado para traer los datos son los siguientes.

```
SELECT
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_Date AS Fecha,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_Name AS Nombre_del_Cliente,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_Company Empresa,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_Tel AS Telefono,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_Job AS Puesto_Del_Cliente,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_Email AS Email,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_Seller AS Ejecutivo_de_ventas_Canon,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.i_Price AS Precio,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_FinanceService AS Servicio_Financiero,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_Service AS Servicio,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_ImgSignSeller AS Firma_Vendedor,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.st_ImgSignClient AS Firma_Cliente,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Cat_Line.st_Line AS Linea,
                C_ExpoGrafica_Cat_Products.st_Product AS Producto 
            FROM
                ideeo_Campaings_SIR.dbo.C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter,
                ideeo_Campaings_SIR.dbo.C_ExpoGrafica_Cat_Line,
                ideeo_Campaings_SIR.dbo.C_ExpoGrafica_Cat_Products,
                ideeo_Campaings_SIR.dbo.C_ExpoGrafica_Rel_BuyLetterProducts 
            WHERE
                C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.id_BuyLetter = C_ExpoGrafica_Rel_BuyLetterProducts.id_BuyLetter AND 
                C_ExpoGrafica_Cat_Line.id_Line = C_ExpoGrafica_Rel_BuyLetterProducts.id_Line AND
                C_ExpoGrafica_Cat_Products.id_Product = C_ExpoGrafica_Rel_BuyLetterProducts.id_Product AND C_ExpoGrafica_Tbl_BuyLetter.id_Status = 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que has intentado hasta ahora? Por favor, pon el codigo que has intentado para que podamos orientar una solucion. Ten en cuenta que con la imagen no podemos suponer como son los datos que llegan de tu bbdd, tu modelo, como lo estas interpretando...

Comment: Bienvenido Jorge. Como te indica @Jakala debes agregar tu código (no te preocupes si no se ve bien, alguien te lo puede editar y formatearlo para que se vea bien. Échale un vistazo a [mcve] para saber como montar una pregunta en la que te puedan responder a lo que buscas. Un saludo!.

Comment: Gracias por responder, he estado buscando poderlo hacerlo desde la base de datos pero ahora lo voy a empezar a realizar con código php

Answer (score 0):

Hola en oracle puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
select   Pais,   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e,ciudad || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',')  Ciudades
from  tablaPais
group by Pais
```

saludos

Comment: Hola Patricio Fernandez, no estoy trabajando con Oracle, actualmente la base de datos la estoy trabajando con sql Server.

Comment: Estimado, encontre esto, al parecer es lo que necesitas

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/3ecd59d2-5eb2-49aa-98ad-d2f1f091b940/concatenar-varias-filas-en-una-sola-sql?forum=sqlserveres


espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias por el link, pero ya lo intente y no funciona =(